How to replace urls and youtube urls and replace the urls as anchor tags and replace youtube urls as Iframe tags
Say if the string returns:
str = `
        https://www.google.com
        http://google.com
        https://www.youtube.com/live/gNIQWYgf-0
        https://www.youtube.com/embed/3ul2LYG6j14?si=fgxYHjyt6zBmoYEr
        https://youtu.be/75Dhfjf6hfjfj
        this also has to take into account the variations of different youtube urls

  `

so when this string comes back I want to wrap the anchor tags for:
<a href="https://www.google.com">https://www.google.com</a>
<a href="https://google.com">https://www.google.com</a>

and wrap the YouTube with iframe tags:
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://youtu.be/75Dhfjf6hfjfj"></iframe>
<iframe width="420" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/3ul2LYG6j14?si=fgxYHjyt6zBmoYEr"></iframe>

I asked this question using the react-native-pell-rich-editor in react-native, because i tried with this method and did not work, im trying with a webview. This question was asked here How do replace urls and youtube urls and replaces the urls as anchor tags and replace youtube urls as Iframe tags
Here is my code:
<WebView source={{
            html: `

                    
                    <!DOCTYPE html>
                    <html>
                        <head>
                            <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
                            
                        </head>
                        <body>
                        <style>
                                [contentEditable=true]:empty:not(:focus):before {
                                    content: attr(data-text);
                                    cursor: text;
                                    color: red;
                                    pointer-events:none;
                                }

                                #placeholder{
                                    position:absolute;
                                    
                                    color:#BDBDBD;font-size:46px;outline:none;
                                }
                                #contentHtml{
                                    position:absolute;
                                    color:black;font-size:46px;outline:none;width:100%;
                                }
                            </style>
                            <div id="contentHtml" contenteditable=true>
                            </div>
                            <div id="placeholder">
                                Enter Comment...
                            </div>
                        </body>
                    </html>
                    <script>
                        $("#placeholder").on("click", function(){
                            //alert("ddd");
                            $("#contentHtml").focus();
                            $(this).hide();
                        })        

                        $("#contentHtml").on("keyup", function(){
                            //alert("ddd");
                            if($("#contentHtml").html().length == 0){
                                $("#placeholder").show();
                            }else{
                                $("#placeholder").hide();
                            }
                        })    
                    </script>
                    
                    `,
        }}
        style={{
            width: '100%',
            height: '100%',
            fontSize:46,
        }}>



    </WebView>

I have managed to get the placeholder working using 2 divs and works ok with the jQuery events, but now I am on the task to take the string from #contentHtml and convert the standard URLs as anchor tags and YouTube URLs as iframe tags.
How can this be achieved in javascript?

To convert standard URLs to anchor tags and YouTube URLs to iframe tags within the content of #contentHtml using JavaScript, you can add a function to perform this conversion and then call it when needed. Here's how you can modify your existing code:
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    $("#placeholder").on("click", function(){
        //alert("ddd");
        $("#contentHtml").focus();
        $(this).hide();
    })        

    $("#contentHtml").on("input", function(){
        //alert("ddd");
        var content = $(this).html();
        var replacedContent = replaceUrls(content);
        $(this).html(replacedContent);
        
        if($(this).text().trim().length === 0){
            $("#placeholder").show();
        } else {
            $("#placeholder").hide();
        }
    });
});

function replaceUrls(content) {
    // Regular expression to identify URLs
    var urlRegex = /(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/g;
    
    // Replace standard URLs with anchor tags
    var replacedContent = content.replace(urlRegex, function(url) {
        return '<a href="' + url + '">' + url + '</a>';
    });

    // Regular expression to identify YouTube URLs
    var youtubeRegex = /(https?:\/\/(?:www\.)?youtube\.com\/watch\?v=([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+))/g;

    // Replace YouTube URLs with iframe tags
    replacedContent = replacedContent.replace(youtubeRegex, function(url, videoId) {
        // Constructing the iframe tag with the video ID
        return '<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/' + videoId + '" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
    });

    return replacedContent;
}


This code snippet modifies your existing code by adding the convertUrlsToHtml function, which is responsible for converting standard URLs to anchor tags and YouTube URLs to iframe tags within the content of #contentHtml.

thanks for the input, i have pasted the code into the webview inside script tag but when i click on the placeholder the place holder does not hide and i just chopped and changed the code from the javascript you added and it seems that the code fails here var urlRegex = /(https?://[^\s]+)/g; but i cant see no errors so not sure

Is the javaScript code executed after the WebView has loaded completely ? Things to check -
Ensure the DOM is fully loaded before executing JavaScript , you can use DOMContentLoaded .
Try to replace keyup event with input event , it detects changes more reliably.
Modify the condition to check if the trimmed text content of #contentHtml is empty to show or hide the placeholder.

i tried the edited code but still no luck

when i take out the code from replaceUrls() the code runs and the alert("ddd"); in the $("#contentHtml").on("input", function(){ fires

when i add the code into a index.html file everything works fine with no errors

i found this on here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64157577/why-does-javascript-not-work-in-rn-webview-but-desktop-browser-works-fine. its saying that the javascrupt only fires when on production environment when using webviews in RN

im testing the RN app on my local iis server that has the webapi web application and its running under http protocol

i also found this that regex in javascript does not allow lookbehind https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68252474/need-alternative-solution-for-regex-in-react-native

not sure if this helps

Did you create this answer with ChatGPT?
